# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. Flip flop

Tags: errors, texstudio, circuitikz

I keep receiving this error when i try to build and view the flip flop D..what should I do?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
    
\begin{circuitikz} [scale=0.9] 
           
    \ctikzset{logic ports=ieee} 
    
    \tikz  \draw (4,7.5) node[and port] (myand1) {}
    (2,5.5) node[ and port] (myand2) {}
    (2,3.5) node[ and port] (myand3) {}
    (4,4.5) node[ or port] (myor) {}
    (4,3.5) node[flipflop D] (D1){}
    
    (myand1.in 1) -|(myand2.in 1)
    (myand2.out) -| (myor.in 1)
    (myand3.out) -| (myor.in 2)
    (myand1.in 1) -|(myand3.in 1);
    
    \end{circuitikz}    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. Side comment: I seriously doubt that you want to issue`\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` _within_ the `curuitikz` environment.

Comment: Why do you have `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` inside a `circuitikz`?

Comment: You also have a `\tikz` command inside   a `circuitikz` environment; remove it. It is probably creating the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks so much guys...i have been stressing over this all night...i made all the adjustments you suggested. it works now!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is resolved in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is the `\tikz` command *inside* the `\begin{circuitikz}...\end{circuitikz}` environment (that is, really, fully equivalent to a `tikzpicture` one).

`\tikz` command is best used for embedding small pictures in text; you should not nest it into the environment...